# Is there a way to create Instagram/TikTok/X user profile page scrollview in iOS17

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I followed a tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQ8ZQIhi8ow) by Kavsoft. This tutorial demonstrates a really popular feature that big social media apps use, such as Instagram, TikTok & X. It's when a user scrolls between their posts, reels & posts tagged in, which is located on Instagram's user profile tab & TikTok has a similar one on its user profile tab. While X has it on its home tab. I can't seem to get it to work if I add a ScrollView.

Now to keep it simple this is how the ProfileScreen looks like:

```
struct ProfileScreen: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: ProfileScreenTabOption? = .media
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView { // Comment Scrollview and it works
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Color.blue
                    .frame(height: 350)
                
                customTabBar()
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    LazyHStack(spacing: 16) {
                        sampleView(.red, count: 3)
                            .id(ProfileScreenTabOption.media)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                        
                        sampleView(.purple, count: 50)
                            .id(ProfileScreenTabOption.saved)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                    }
                    .scrollTargetLayout()
                }
                //Uncomment to play around with height 
                //.frame(height: selectedTab == .media ? 300 : 1000)
                .scrollPosition(id: $selectedTab)
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ProfileScreen uses an enum that only has 2 cases media & saved:

```
enum ProfileScreenTabOption: Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case media
    case saved
    
    var id: Self {
        return self
    }
    
    var systemName: String {
        switch self {
        case .media: "photo.on.rectangle"
        case .saved: "bookmark"
        }
    }
}
```

The ProfileScreen also uses 2 ViewBuilders:

```
extension ProfileScreen {
    private func customTabBar() -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(ProfileScreenTabOption.allCases) { tab in
                Image(systemName: tab.systemName)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 29)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.snappy(duration: 0.1)) {
                            selectedTab = tab
                        }
                    }
                    
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func sampleView(_ color: Color, count: Int) -> some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1), count: 3), spacing: 1) {
                ForEach(1...count, id: \.self) { x in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                        .fill(color.gradient)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay {
                            Text("\(x)")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollDisabled(true) // comment this with ProfileScreen ScrollView
    }
}
```

I tried to get this to work for a couple of hours but no luck. I know now that it has to do with the nested ScrollView that contains the sampleViews. I also tried changing the LazyHStack inside the nested ScrollView to an HStack but this makes the Scroll View height the height of the sampleView that has the highest height. When scrolling you will see unwanted white space for the smallest sampleView. I also tried changing the height of the nested ScrollView but its an ugly transition.

Now is there a way to get this to work or a package that does this in SwiftUI?